# Access to last command in Zsh (not previous command line)

Tags: zsh

Is there a way to retrieve the text of the last command in Zsh? I mean the last executed command, not the last command line.

### What was tried

Trying to do it, I discovered a subtle difference between Zsh and Bash handling of history. This difference is exposed in the following sample, which is the base of what I was doing in Bash, and which does not work in Zsh.

```
$ zsh
$ echo "This is command #1"
> This is command #1
$ echo "This is command #2"; echo $(history | tail -n1)
> This is command #2
> 3807 echo "This is command #1"

$ bash
$ echo "This is command #1"
> This is command #1
$ echo "This is command #2"; echo $(history | tail -n1)
> This is command #2
> 4970 echo "This is command #2"; echo $(history | tail -n1)
```

Same tests, whose result differs in the last line. Bash appends the command line to the history, *before execution* (I don't know if it's by specification), while Zsh seems to append the command line to the history, *after execution* (the same, I don't know if it's by specification), thus `history | tail -n1` does not give the same.

What I want, is to be able to retrieve `echo "This is command #2"`, that is, the text of the previous command even when it's on the same command line as other commands (when there are multiple command separated with `;`).

With bash, I could use `history | tail -n1 | sed ...`, but this does not work any more with Zsh, due the difference in history handling.

### What needs to be achieved

Any idea on how to get the last command from a multi‑command command line in Zsh?

I need it for when a command needs to know what was the previous command, whatever that command was on the same line or the previous line. Another way to say it, could be: I need to access the last item of a single command oriented history, not of a command(s) line oriented history.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I'm aware of there is no easy way to this in zsh. I believe the closest answer to your question in interactive shell is to use history expansion mechanism, especially `!#`, but you may be interested in `!!`, `!!:1` and others as well. From zsh manual:

> !#     Refer to the current command line typed in so
>   far.

So you can do the following to get previous command:

```
echo "This is command #1"; var=$(echo !#) && echo "The previous command was:" \'$var\'
```

And  the result is

```
This is command #1
The previous command was: 'echo This is command #1'
```

You can also play with

```
echo "This is command 1"; var=$(echo "!#:s/;//") && echo "The previous command was:" \'$var\'
```

if you would need to enclose `!#` with double quotes, but in this case you have to remove `;` from the end of the "last command". `:s/;//` is doing that. More sophisticated commands are now working well:

```
ls >/dev/null 2>&1; var=$(echo "!#:s/;//") && print "The previous command was:" \'$var\'
```

gives the output:

```
ls >/dev/null 2>&1; var=$(echo "ls >/dev/null 2>&1") && print "The previous command was:" $var
The previous command was: 'ls >/dev/null 2>&1'
```

Notice however that in this case `#` should not be present in the first command together with quotes as it will be interpreted as comment.

**Note 1**

It is important here that `!#` represents everything what is present in the current line so far *except* a current atom, thus `var` in the expression

```
echo "This is command #1"; var=$(echo !#) && echo "The previous command was:" \'$var\'
```

is in fact equal to:

```
var=$(echo echo "This is command #1";)
```

so that `echo $var` prints `echo This is command #1` as mentioned before.
But if we write simplified version, without variable:

```
echo "This is command #1"; echo "The previous command was:" !#
```

then `!#` would contain additional, second `echo` and its argument, so actually command would become:

> echo "This is command #1"; echo "The previous command was:" echo "This
>   is command #1"; echo "The previous command was:"

**Note 2**

This solution is obviously not perfect because, as you may noticed, quotes are not included into variable. You can try to workaround about it with appending single quotes around `!#` *but not directly* (otherwise history expansion won't work).

**Note 3**

If you have more than 3 or more commands in one line, separated with `;`, than you would need to play a little bit more with zsh modifiers or with outside commands like sed or awk.

Comment: “everything what is present in the current line so far except a current atom”: what is an atom in Zsh? Is this in the doc? By the way, the doc refers to word, without an explicit definition of it (I just guessed).

Comment: `Atom` is just a word which I believe the best describes what I had in mind. The point is that `!#` does not exactly gather everything typed till `!#` - you can use `var="!#"` and `var="` will not be present after history expansion. I don't know how to name it better, but compare result of two commands: `echo foo !#` and `echo "foo !#"`. The first one contains 3 atoms (`echo`, `foo` and `!#`) but the second only two (`echo` and `"foo !#"`). I edited **Note 1** in my answer, hopefully it is clearer now.

Comment: Do you know if it's by specification or is this an implementation effect? This is to know if it's reliable.

Comment: From zsh manual I guess it is by specification: `The line is treated as if it were complete up to and including the word before the one  with  the  '!#'`. They obviously call word what I called an atom. However keep in mind that for example bash works differently, so `echo "foo !#"` expands to `echo "foo echo "foo "` and produces nothing because quotes do not match.

Answer (score 8):

An attempt to answer my own question. I still welcome other's answers, as this one is not perfect.

At least, there's a way to get the same as with Bash, using the `$history` array and the `$HISTCMD` index. Example:

```
$ zsh
$ echo "This is command #3"; echo $history[$HISTCMD]
> This is command #3
> echo "This is command #3"; echo $history[$HISTCMD]
```

This gives back the same as `history | tail -n1` in Bash and I can apply `sed` on this. But relying on `sed` is precisely the reason why this answer is not totally perfect; it's error‑prone to parse a command line with regular expressions, especially with an as much complex shell syntax as that of Zsh is.

Comment: nice, this is exactly what I needed! I wanted to fix the good old `alert` alias for zsh